# Prevent datagrid column resize on datagrid resize

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with columns with great difference in width. They are not autogenerated. I would like to prevent some of these columns to be stretched when the window containing the datagrid is resized.

the definition of the datagrid is like this in XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DatagridControl" Grid.Row="1"  CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Variables, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVariable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BeginningEdit="DatagridControl_BeginningEdit" HeadersVisibility="Column" FontSize="16">
```

I have some columns where I know what would be the minimum size so they are defined like this and it works like I want

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dataGridTextColumConnectorLogo" Width="auto"  MinWidth="50" CanUserResize="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Width="40" Height="40">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="materialDesign:PackIcon">
                        <Setter Property="Kind" Value="PipeDisconnected"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" ></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectorType}" Value="ads">
                                <Setter Property="Kind" Value="AlphaBBox"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" ></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </materialDesign:PackIcon.Style>
            </materialDesign:PackIcon>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But there a some colums where I can't set the minwith because I don't know the size of the content. So I put them of width=auto but how can I prevent them to be streched when the datagrid is resized ? Is is possible to bind the width of the element inside the cell to force this ?

Comment: Can't you handle the `Loaded` event and set the `MinWidth` or `MaxWidth` property of this column to its calculated `ActualWidth`?

Comment: following your advice I forced the `MinWidth` to be the `ActualWidth` in the `SizeChanged` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle an event such as `SizeChanged` and set the `MinWidth` property of the column to its calculated `ActualWidth` in this event handler.